# SQLITE FTS3 Query Slower than Standard Tabel

Tags: sql, sqlite, fts3

I built sqlite3 from source to include the FTS3 support and then created a new table in an existing sqlite database containing 1.5million rows of data, using

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE data USING FTS3(codes text);
```

Then used

```
INSERT INTO data(codes) SELECT originalcodes FROM original_data;
```

Then queried each table with

```
SELECT * FROM original_data WHERE originalcodes='RH12';
```

This comes back instantly as I have an index on that column

The query on the FTS3 table

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE codes='RH12';
```

Takes almost 28 seconds

Can someone help explain what I have done wrong as I expected this to be significantly quicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_4) explains:

> FTS tables can be queried efficiently using SELECT statements of two different forms:
>
> - Query by rowid. If the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement contains a sub-clause of the form "rowid = ?", where ? is an SQL expression, FTS is able to retrieve the requested row directly using the equivalent of an SQLite INTEGER PRIMARY KEY index.
> - Full-text query. If the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement contains a sub-clause of the form " MATCH ?", FTS is able to use the built-in full-text index to restrict the search to those documents that match the full-text query string specified as the right-hand operand of the MATCH clause.
>
> If neither of these two query strategies can be used, all queries on FTS tables are implemented using a linear scan of the entire table.

For an efficient query, you should use

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE codes MATCH 'RH12'
```

but this will find all records that *contain* the search string.

To do 'normal' queries efficiently, you have to keep a copy of the data in a normal table.
(If you want to save space, you can use a [contentless or external content](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2) table.)

Answer (score 0):

You should read [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_4) more carefully.

Any query against virtual FTS table using `WHERE col = 'value'` will be slow (except for query against `ROWID`), but query using `WHERE col MATCH 'value'` will be using FTS and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but here are a few things to think about.
Your test is flawed (I think). You are contrasting a scenario where you have an exact text match (the index can be used on original_data - nothing is going to outperform this scenario) with an equality on the fts3 table (I'm not sure that FTS3 would even come into play in this type of query). If you want to compare apples to apples (to see the benefit of FTS3), you're going to want to compare a "like" operation on original_data against the FTS3 "match" operation on data.